# Integrating Swarm in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I'm trying to integrate Swarm in my game but it does not work, I'm using andengine GLES2. All I want is a Leaderboard integrate and if I do it as a separate activity that extends SwarmActivity if it works but I want to integrate it into a BaseGameActivity.

Thank you.

```
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Cargo la escena del Cargando
    mScene = new Scene();
    mScene.setBackgroundEnabled(false);
    mScene.attachChild(new Sprite(0, 0, mSplashBackgroundTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()));       

    this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
    this.mScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);      

    Swarm.init(this, SWARM_APP_ID, SWARM_APP_KEY, mySwarmLoginListener);

    Swarm.setActive(this);

    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(this.mScene);

}

public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene arg0, TouchEvent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

    SwarmLeaderboard.getLeaderboardById(LEADERBOARD_ID, new GotLeaderboardCB() {
        public void gotLeaderboard(SwarmLeaderboard leaderboard) {

            if (leaderboard != null) {

                // Save a local reference to the leaderboard
                SwActivity.leaderboard = leaderboard;

                // Submit the score to the leaderboard 
                SwActivity.leaderboard.submitScore(1000f);

                SwActivity.leaderboard.showLeaderboard();
            }
        }
    }); 

    return false;
}
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Swarm.setActive(this);              
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Swarm.setInactive(this);
}

private SwarmLoginListener mySwarmLoginListener = new SwarmLoginListener() {

    public void loginCanceled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void loginStarted() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void userLoggedIn(SwarmActiveUser user) {
        // Load our Leaderboard
        SwarmLeaderboard.getLeaderboardById(LEADERBOARD_ID, new GotLeaderboardCB() {
            public void gotLeaderboard(SwarmLeaderboard lb) {
                leaderboard = lb;
            }
        });         

    }

    public void userLoggedOut() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending SwarmActivity simply adds calls to Swarm.setActive(context) and as part of onCreate, onResume, and Swarm.setInactive(context) as part of the onPause.  If you can grab a handle to the context, you should be able to make those calls yourself in equivalent places.

If you'd like a fully opensourced custom example that uses AndEngine + Swarm, there's one available here: http://swarmconnect.com/admin/docs/kissthefish.  If that still doesn't make sense, please send an email to support(at)swarmconnect[dot]com and someone will help you out from there :).

Cheers!